# Accessing a record from an association set

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing a web application with ASP.net MVC and I have a database which I'm connecting with an ADO.NET Entity Framework.

In this database I have a table Group with GroupId as a primary key, another table UserInfo with UserId as its primary key and another table GroupUser which is not considered as an Entity but rather as an Association Set since it is used as a mean to have a many to many relationship between Group and User.

`GroupUser` contains `GroupId` and `UserId` as a composite key and both are foreign keys to the respective tables.

These are the `Group` and `User` classes generated (regarding this relationship)

```
// Group
public Group()
{
    this.UserInfo1 = new HashSet<UserInfo>();
}

public virtual UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<UserInfo> UserInfo1 { get; set; }

// UserInfo
public UserInfo()
{
   this.Group = new HashSet<Group>();
   this.Group1 = new HashSet<Group>();
}

public virtual ICollection<Group> Group { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Group> Group1 { get; set; }
```

To add a record to this `GroupUser` table I am doing this

```
int ownerId = Convert.ToInt32(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
group.UserInfo1.Add(conn.UserInfo.Find(ownerId));
```

However I am stuck on how to find a record in this table. How can I check if a particular user belongs to this group by having groupId and userId provided here?

```
Group group = conn.Group.Find(id);
int userId = Convert.ToInt32(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);
```

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the starting point you have provided in order to test if the user is in that group you can use:

```
Group group = conn.Group.Find(id);
int userId = Convert.ToInt32(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

bool isUserInGroup = group.UserInfo1.Any(u => u.UserId == userId);
```

It will work because when you access `group.UserInfo1` (with the `Any` extension method in this case) Entity Framework will run a second query (the first one was `Find`) to load all related `UserInfo` entities of the given `group` into the `group.UserInfo1` collection. This query is based in *lazy loading* which is enabled by default if the navigation collection is declared as `virtual` (which it is in your example). After loading the collection the `Any` call is a check in memory (no database query here anymore) if the `group.UserInfo1` collection contains at least one entity that fulfills the supplied condition, i.e. contains a user with that `userId`.

However, this is not the best solution because - as said - it will cause two queries (`Find` and lazy loading of the collection). Actually you can test if the user is in the group by a single database query alone and you don't even need to load any entities for that test, just directly return the `bool` result from the database:

```
int userId = Convert.ToInt32(WebSecurity.CurrentUserId);

bool isUserInGroup = conn.Group
    .Any(g => g.GroupId == id && g.UserInfo1.Any(u => u.UserId == userId));
```

The result will be `false` if the group with the `id` does not exist or if it doesn't have a related user with `userId`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed answer @Slauma! You helped me understand this to the full. +1 :)